# Check if an argument from CMD has written or not using Python

Tags: python

I'm new in python and I am trying to build a script that gets as an argument a URL and send a GET request to the website and then print the details from the response and the HTML body as well.

The code I wrote:

```
import sys
import urllib.request

url = 'https://%s' % (sys.argv[1])
res = urllib.request.urlopen(url)
print('Response from the server:'+'\n', res.info())
print('HTML web page:'+'\n', res.read())
```

Now, I want to check if an argument is passed through the CMD or not and if not to alert about it.
And also to print the Status Code and the Reason.
What is exactly Reason means?
This is what I got so far and I do not understand why I don't get any result.

My current code is:

```
import sys
import urllib.request, urllib.error

try:
    url = 'https://%s' % (sys.argv[1])
    res = urllib.request.urlopen(url)
except IndexError:
    if len(sys.argv) < 1:
        print(res.getcode())
        print(res.getreason())
    elif len(sys.argv) > 1:
        print('Response from the server:'+'\n', res.info())
        print('HTML web page:'+'\n', res.read())
        print('Status Code:', res.getcode())
```

Thank you.

Comment: you are printing the reponse in the except block. Move the print statements inside the else statements into the try block.I tried hardcoding the url and tested it. works fine

Comment: @DineshKumar , can you please attach me the code? I don't understand.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `except` block will get executed only when you dont give any arguments in your command line.Basically only when an IndexError exception is raised.I believe just printing the error message should suffice in that usecase. The print statements should be handled inside the `try` block.

```
import sys
import urllib
from urllib2 import URLError

try:
    url = 'https://%s' % (sys.argv[1])
    #url = r'https://www.google.com'
    res = urllib.urlopen(url)
    print('Response from the server:' + '\n', res.info())
    print('HTML web page:' + '\n', res.read())
    print('Status Code:', res.getcode())
except IndexError as e:
    print e.message
except URLError as e1:
    print e1.reason
```

Note : I am using python 2.7. So I did not use urllib.request.urlopen() as this is not necessary in python 2.x

Comment: How can I print the Reason?

Comment: Do u mean reason for the Index Error?

Answer (score 0):

You're only checking if `len(sys.argv) < 1 or len(sys.argv) > 1` and never if `len(sys.argv) == 1`, which it will be if you run the script without any arguments, since `sys.argv[0]` is the name of the script.

In addition, if you use `except IndexError`, you are essentially handling (or supposed to handle) the exception, so python exits without an error without hitting any case in your `if-elif` clause.

You could do something like this:

```
import sys
import urllib

try:
    url = 'https://%s' % (sys.argv[1])
    res = urllib.request.urlopen(url)

except IndexError:
    if len(sys.argv) <= 1:
        print("Too few arguments")
        raise # <- or replace with sys.exit(1) if you don't want to propagate the exception
```

The actual `urllib.request.urlopen(url)` might throw other exceptions though. I would be careful with handling command line arguments in the same `try-except` block as the http request.